# Which SSDs are compatible with the Lenovo x260?

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I'm looking at potentially purchasing a Lenovo x260, but I'm curious if it's possible to upgrade a 256GB SSD to a 512GB or 1TB SSD. Which SSDs are compatible with this unit?

Comment: Just about every single modern pc employs a standard SATA connection - and has a 2.5" HDD slot. Those are your criteria to meet, which just about every single SSD will meet. ( with the exception of PCI / PCIe SSD drives ) As far as the upgrad, you can mirror the smaller disk to the larger disk - and then expand the partition to use up all unallocated space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why any SATA SSD drive would **NOT** work since this laptop has a standard SATA interface.

According to [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/thinkpad-x260), all their SATA SSD drives are compatible and this should be a fairly good representation of all manufacturer's industry standard SATA SSD drives.

You should not have any compatible issues with standard SSD drives in this device, regardless of size.

Comment: Something to note is you want a Z height SSD usually. Most SSDs are that height, but if you want to play it safe...